# Use Truth to compare proto to string

Tags: google-truth

Is there a way to use [Google Truth](https://google.github.io/truth/) to compare a protobuff to a string? I am hoping to find something that looks like this:

```
assertThat(myProto).isEqualToString("a: 1\n b:2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Truth provides an [extension](https://google.github.io/truth/extension) for [protocol buffer assertions](https://google.github.io/truth/api/latest/com/google/common/truth/extensions/proto/ProtoSubject.html), which is probably what you should use. Asserting on a message's string format is going to be brittle, and failures will be harder to understand.

That said you certainly *can* do what you're asking:

```
assertThat(myProto.toString()).isEqualTo("a: 1\n b:2");
```